# Groovy rosmake fails on package with action (1st time)

Tags: ros, action, ros-groovy, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Groovy, rosmake fails the first time it is run on the [industrial_msgs package](http://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Findustrial_core%2Findustrial_msgs).  This doesn't occur in Fuerte.  The output of rosmake is shown below.  Commenting out:

```
rosbuild_find_ros_package(actionlib_msgs)
include(${actionlib_msgs_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/actionbuild.cmake)
genaction()
```

in the CMakeLists.txt (also shown below) results in a successful build.  The package also successfully builds the second time that rosmake is ran (without commenting out anything in CMakeLists.txt.  Has anybody seen this or know of a solution?

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_find_ros_package(actionlib_msgs)
include(${actionlib_msgs_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/actionbuild.cmake)
genaction()

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

**rosmake output**

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesdustrial_msgs: 25.8 sec ]                                  [ 1 Active 5/7 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 
  -- Action Files:
  [rosbuild] Building package industrial_msgs
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/sedwards/ros/groovy/ros_industrial_trunk/industrial_core/industrial_msgs/build/devel
  -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
  -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
  -- Found gtest: gtests will be built
  -- catkin 0.5.63
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:369 (add_custom_target):
    add_custom_target cannot create target "rosbuild_premsgsrvgen" because
    another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
    custom target created in source directory
    "/home/sedwards/ros/groovy/ros_industrial_trunk/industrial_core/industrial_msgs".
    See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:15 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  [rosbuild] WARNING: rosbuild_genmsg() was called, but the roslang package cannot be found.  Message generation will NOT occur
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:790 (add_dependencies):
    add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target:
    rosbuild_precompile
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:23 (rosbuild_genmsg)
  
  
  [rosbuild] WARNING: rosbuild_gensrv() was called, but the roslang package cannot be found. Service generation will NOT occur
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:753 (add_dependencies):
    add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target:
    rosbuild_precompile
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:25 (rosbuild_gensrv)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56083/groovy-rosmake-fails-on-package-with-action-(1st-time)/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that the action that was being generated was removed a long time ago.  The action building scripts were left in the CMakeLists.txt.  Removing the calls fixed the problem (obviously).  My best guess, although I haven't verified this, is that the make functions fail or hang if an action is not defined.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1